# Last page and First page Gives Exception in MVC paging

Tags: asp.net, gridview, paging

```
 protected void gvValues_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {
            gvValues.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            this.FillData();
        }
```

paging works fine but when I clcik on last or First it gives me Error as

```
Input string was not in a correct format.
```

Comment: OK, I did , what shall I do also ?
I tried to make switch loop to make index correctly but I didn't know where shall I put this loop

Comment: Can you look at my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Write following code :

```
protected void gvValues_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e){

    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;

    //rebind your gridview - GetSource(),Datasource of your GirdView
    GridView1.DataSource = GetSource();
    GridView1.DataBind();

}
```

Comment: I bind it in my original code look at my updated question, and my paging works correctly in 123456 ... but when I press last page it gives me this exception